# JavaScript: How to decode polyline from MySQL database

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-maps-api-3, encode, polyline

I want to load polyline path from database. I tried it with one encode polyline in variable, but it's not showing the polyline. This is my code snippet:

```js
var polylayer = ['munoEub_uSEGDFMKLJYSXRa@Y`@Xq@e@p@d@w@i@v@h@eAu@']

addEncodedPaths( encodedFlightPaths );

function addEncodedPaths( encodedPaths ) {
    for( var i = 0, n = encodedPaths.length;  i < n;  i++ ) {
        addEncodedPath( encodedPaths[i] );
    }
}

function addEncodedPath( encodedPath ) {
    var path = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath( encodedPath );

    var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: path,
        strokeColor: "#0000FF",
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
    });
    polyline.setMap( map );
}
```

Comment: you pass the wrong argument to `addEncodedPaths`, it has to be `polylayer` instead of `encodedFlightPaths`

Comment: @Dr.Molle I see, but it keep not showing polyline, what should I do?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q22zv8a4/